# Possible to have a small UITable in a View?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is it possible to have a small UITable in a view, where when you click a cell, the small table is transitioned to the detail level? I currently have it so that the whole screen slides to the detail level.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have to do is create another view controller and lay it over the top.

to make a UITableView co-exist with a UINavigationController you have to create a transparent view to hold it. the view will be fullscreen so it does not resize the embedded UITable

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating a UITableView/UITableViewController, create a UIView/UIViewController and drag-drop the UITableView to your UIView. Set the size and position of the tableview as you want and make the UIViewController the tableview's delegate and datasource.

Comment: That is currently what i am doing however, i need to add a navigation controller... i do this in app delegate. should i move the navigation controller?